# how to split a tuple with 2 arrays into 2 arrays?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to split wine data (dt) in sklearn into 2 arrays:
this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
dt = load_wine(return_X_y=True)
```

dt is like this:

> (array([[1.423e+01, 1.710e+00, 2.430e+00, ..., 1.040e+00, 3.920e+00,
> 1.065e+03],
> [1.320e+01, 1.780e+00, 2.140e+00, ..., 1.050e+00, 3.400e+00,
> 1.050e+03],
> [1.316e+01, 2.360e+00, 2.670e+00, ..., 1.030e+00, 3.170e+00,
> 1.185e+03],
> ...,
> [1.327e+01, 4.280e+00, 2.260e+00, ..., 5.900e-01, 1.560e+00,
> 8.350e+02],
> [1.317e+01, 2.590e+00, 2.370e+00, ..., 6.000e-01, 1.620e+00,
> 8.400e+02],
> [1.413e+01, 4.100e+00, 2.740e+00, ..., 6.100e-01, 1.600e+00,
> 5.600e+02]]),
> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2]))

I would like to split dt into:

> (array([[1.423e+01, 1.710e+00, 2.430e+00, ..., 1.040e+00, 3.920e+00,
> 1.065e+03],
> [1.320e+01, 1.780e+00, 2.140e+00, ..., 1.050e+00, 3.400e+00,
> 1.050e+03],
> [1.316e+01, 2.360e+00, 2.670e+00, ..., 1.030e+00, 3.170e+00,
> 1.185e+03],
> ...,
> [1.327e+01, 4.280e+00, 2.260e+00, ..., 5.900e-01, 1.560e+00,
> 8.350e+02],
> [1.317e+01, 2.590e+00, 2.370e+00, ..., 6.000e-01, 1.620e+00,
> 8.400e+02],
> [1.413e+01, 4.100e+00, 2.740e+00, ..., 6.100e-01, 1.600e+00,
> 5.600e+02]]),

and

> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2]))

np.split
but did not work

What I would like to do is make an matrix like this: the last column is "class" and the other columns are variables.

I'm new to python, don't know how to do this.

The data structure of `load_wine()` looks strange to me: variables are in an array, and "class" are in another array.

Comment: What's wrong with `dt[0]` and `dt[1]`?

Comment: cool!
thanks!
so dt here is like a list in R.
dt[0] is like dt[1] in R.
that make sense

Comment: `dt` is a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), with 0-indexed elements (so `dt[0]` is the first element in the tuple). If `dt == (1, 2)` then `dt[0] == 1` and `dt[1] == 2`